# text-shadow won't render if blur radius is given in Safari

Tags: css, reactjs

Haven't a really interesting time with a text-shadow on this page.

http://lunareee.onuniverse.com

The top title "Lunareee" has a text-shadow on it. If you check the inspector you can see it should be.

`text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 10px;`

This works fine in any stand alone example I can setup so its some reaction issue but I can't figure out what it could possibly be. In the inspector, if I set a custom text-shadow to play with, as long as the blur is `0px` it works. As soon as I set it to 1 or higher the shadow disappears.

Another interesting note. In Safari on Mac, if you click the text, the shadow appears.

Anyone have any ideas what other CSS could be conflicting here?

**Update**
http://onuniverse-sandbox.com/0265DF42-1A4A-4F74-AAAE-DFC8B47C7720

Managed to isolate it within our own system. Its related some how to our shape masking. Anyone know of any thing within CSS that would conflict with `text-shadow`s as it relates to masking?

**Update**

Removing the `border-radius: 45px;` makes the shadow work perfectly. But I wasn't able to recreate that here. https://jsfiddle.net/zugq7upa/ The border-radius and text-shadow work fine together in this simple example. So its another weird interaction tied to something in our sites. Definitely curious if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: As a note, looking at this in Safari 10.1.2 on a Mac, I don't see any border radius anywhere (assuming you took that off in one of the updates?), and even still, I don't see the text-shadow when the page initially loads. What I do see is that a `text-shadow` is applied one letter at a time as I highlight letters. I see a text shadow on every line on your sandbox page.

Comment: Yea I removed border-radius to get this working. But I was just wondering why it have any effect on text-shadow to begin with. We're masking the blocks with an svg to get the rounded corners. border-radius was probably legacy code in this case. But I don't understand why removing it fixed things.

Comment: Well what I was saying was I'm not sure it was related at all since I still saw the problem without a border radius (unless I just missed it?). But it's working for me now!